# Sun's Right Ascension appears to be wrong in my Stellarium

Tags: astronomy, software

The [Stellarium](http://www.stellarium.org/) version 0.12.4 I have shows the RA of the sun at 22.5 Hour while Google says it is 19h 4m 31s. I am confused. Please help.

Comment: Um, are you sure this is a *physics* question?

Comment: Astronomy is on topic here too.

Comment: Maybe Astronomy SE then?

Comment: No, astronomy is on topic here too. If Bibhu doesn't find a good answer here he can try his luck there, but there is no reason to move on-topic questions to beta sites.

Answer (score 1):

Given we are less than a month away from the equinox, I guess Stellarium is right.

Comment: This would be great if you could give a sentence or two explaining how the Sun's RA varies over the course of the year.

Comment: The sun's right ascension is similar to longitude.  As the earth rotates around the sun, the sun's apparent position relative to the stars (much further away) changes.  In the same way that longitude zero is defined to go through Greenwich, right ascension zero is the right ascension of the sun on the spring equinox.  As the sun goes all the way round in 12 months, its average is 2 hours per month.  We are less than month away from thr spring equinox, so the sun's RA will be within 2 hours of 0 (or 24).

Comment: @Dr Chuck Does google not update this information? Stellarium  agrees with google on RA of Sirius (approx 6h 45m 9s) but not on Sun. My doubt is which value am I to trust?

Comment: I don't know what Google does, but as you surmise, it does not (currently) update the sun's RA.  I can't vouch for Stellarium but I have no reason to believe that it is inaccurate.  Try some other free software, such as Cartes du Ciel to do a check.

Answer (score 1):

As of July 27, 2014, Google still says the Sun is at RA 19h 4 m 31 s, Dec 63° 52.200':

[image]

That's so embarrassing, Google!

So what are those coordinates? They obviously aren't the coordinates of the Sun from a geocentric perspective. The geocentric right ascension and declination of the Sun vary with time. Those coordinates are instead the coordinates of the Sun's north pole from the perspective of a heliocentric (sun-centered) frame whose axes are parallel to those of the International Celestial Reference Frame.